# подключение пхп

Tags: php

как правильно подключить пхп файл??

Comment: Куда? Сформулируйте четко свой вопрос.

Comment: Переформулируйте, пока не поздно.А так,если через PHP подключить PHP скрипт ещё один,то `include 'path_script.php';`

Answer (score 1):

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/include/block-header.php');
```

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` директория корня документов

Answer (score 1):

Подключение осуществляется конструкциями:

- `require`, `require_once`
- `include`, `include_once`

В качестве параметра к этим выражениям передается путь к файлу, или от директорий заданных директивой `include_path`, или относительный(от пути где лежит подключающий файл), или абсолютный от корня файловой системы(если указывается путь).